# how to data recovery at github?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I lost data while using github......

I developed code to acquire data and managed it in a GitHub repository using the GitHub desktop.

Because the data stored in my code is large
Only developed codes were committed without committing to the GitHub repository.

While committing to GitHub, a large amount of data was committed together, and I pressed “Undo” on the GitHub desktop to solve the problem, but my data was lost as it was restored to the previous version without data..

The data that was not uploaded to the github repository disappeared when reverting to the previous version.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

please help me....

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to use GitHub well, so I've only used commit and push.

Comment: run `git log` find the commit that has the data. Roll the `HEAD` back to that `commit id`